# How to redirect the specific product page when i click the add to cart button instead of add the product to cart in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, redirect, magento2.3.2, magento2.3.3

I want to redirect the specific product page when i click the add to cart button instead of add the product to cart in magento 2.3.2

If anyone know the answer please share the exact code and folder structure since i'm new to magento.

Answer (score 0):

you need to overide addtocart.phtml file.

here is the code
app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>

        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Extension::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>

    </body>
</page>
```

Now, create phtml file.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\templates\catalog\product\view\addtocart.phtml

Put below code at addtocart.phtml

```
    <?php $_product = $block->getProduct();
?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       maxlength="12"
                       value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
                <button type="button" title="Titel" class="action primary tocart" onclick="setProductData('<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>')"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo 'button text' ?></span></button>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php else : ?>
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'mage/mage',
        'Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation',
        'Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart'
    ], function ($) {
        'use strict';

        $('#product_addtocart_form').mage('validation', {
            radioCheckboxClosest: '.nested',
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                var widget = $(form).catalogAddToCart({
                    bindSubmit: false
                });

                widget.catalogAddToCart('submitForm', $(form));

                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

it will work, Happy Coding :)

Comment: it's not working. i have created new module like Custom_Addtocart. and created the phtml file and xml file which you have mentioned the file path. after that i have clicked the add to cart button still its adding the product.

Comment: Have you created registration.php and etc/module.xml file?

Comment: yes. i have created registration.php file and module.xml file.

Comment: xml and phtml file added app/code/Custom/addtocart/view/layout and /templates folder ?

Comment: now i'm trying another way like paste the code under design/frontend/vendor/themename/Magento_Catalog following same file path which you're shared.

Comment: yes. i have created the xml file under app/code/Custom/addtocart/view/layout. and created the phtml file under  templates\catalog\product\view\.

Comment: button text added in the product page. but my question is I need to redirect the specific product page when i click the add to cart button in the category page. instead of add the product to the shopping cart

Comment: Now  only simple things , you just need to replace button to your link and give the class "primary action" to your a tag.